# Getting Error while runing command ng serve

Tags: angular

WARNING in ./node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015/ng2-charts.js 226:40-58

"export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that some libraries' version are incompatible with Angular's version. Try setting `skipLibCheck` to `true` in `compilerOptions` inside the file tsconfig.json may help

```
"compilerOptions": {
   "skipLibCheck": true,
},
```